# wp_list_categories: How to get the tag outside of tag

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

I creating a list of categories...
how to make each whole 'line' of the list become a link

```
<?php 
    wp_list_categories( $args );
?>
```

instead of below code

```
<li><a href="">Category</a></li>
```

I need below code

```
<a href=""><li>Category</li></a>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: This is invalid html...

Comment: That is invalid HTML, are you trying to make each whole 'line' of the list become a link? If so you can do this with the original code and some CSS

Comment: thanks rnevius «make each whole 'line' of the list become a link»  with set display:block for anchor tag problem resolved

Answer (score 0):

```css
a{display:block;}
```

```html
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431390/wp-list-categories-how-to-get-the-tag-outside-of-tag">Category</a></li>
```